# TestFlight doesn't show my App name

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, testflight

I can see just an empty field where the App name should be displayed.

What can cause this issue?

Which exactly the field of project settings does TestFlight use for displaying of an App name?

Answer (score 0):

It must be bundle display name. You can find it at target -> info -> Custom iOS target properties or in your PROJECT_NAME-info.plist file.

Comment: Sure, there is localized value `${CFBundleDisplayName}`, which has taken from .strings localized file

Answer (score 0):

Check for your project settings -> target -> general -> BundleIdentifier
check for bundleIdentifier is it ends with your app name or not.
if it doesn't end with your app name than go to -info.plist file and change the bundle display name to your app and Bundleidentifier to your yourappid.appname

Comment: bundle display name in info.plist is localized, so I have ${CFBundleDisplayName} there as a value, as such, my bundle identifier's app name can't be matched with bundle display name from info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this user's device was grant permission to access the build on testflightapp.